# How i build Dynamicx queries elasticsearch_dsl python

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following problem with the elasticsearch_dsl python library.

I am developing a web application (DJANGO framework) with search functionality. I want to build a dynamic query, must mode.

So here it is the following code

```
i = 0
must = []
while (i < len(results['words'])):
    must.append(Q('match', tags=results['words'][i]))
    i += 1

print must
client = Elasticsearch()
es = Search(using=client, index="_______")
es.query(must)
response = es.execute()
for hit in response:
    print hit
return response.hits.total
```

Python returns exceptions.TypeError

I have already the documentation of elasticsearch_dsl but i didn't find something like my issue. Do you know the way how i fix this problem?

Comment: did the solution work?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the delayed response. Your answer was to the point

Answer (score 2):

You are kind of close. You need to specify `bool` and then query on the `Search` object like this

```
i = 0
must = []
while (i < len(results['words'])):
    must.append(Q('match', tags=results['words'][i]))
    i += 1

print must
client = Elasticsearch()
q = Q('bool', must=must)   <--- This is important
es = Search(using=client, index="_______").query(q)
response = es.execute()
for hit in response:
    print hit
return response.hits.total
```

You can also see the actual query with `es.to_dict()` which can help you understand

Comment: Your immediately answer was quite helpful. If i have the right reputation I'll give you a vote up.